# Displaying the value of a column based on criteria | MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Essentially I have a query that should contain a column that displays data from two different columns based on the criteria of another column, using an expression.

If `Column1` says: "Ready" or "Almost" the value of Column2 should be presented

If `Column1` says: "Working" or "Tired" the value of Column3 should be presented

I have written the following expression:

```
IIf([Column1]="Ready" Or "Almost",[Column2],IIf([Column1]="Working" Or "Tired", [Column3]))
```

Using the expression above, the correct values for the records containing "Working" or "Tired" seem to be displaying the value of `Column2` not `Column3`. What is the issue with the expression?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare both values (e.g. `Ready` and `Almost`) explicitely: `[Column1]="Ready" Or [Column1]="Almost"`.

So the expression will be:

```
IIf([Column1]="Ready" Or [Column1]="Almost", [Column2],
  IIf([Column1]="Working" Or [Column1]="Tired", [Column3]))
```

But you can also use the `Switch` function, which can make it more clear:

```
Switch(
  [Column1]="Ready" Or [Column1]="Almost", [Column2],
  [Column1]="Working" Or [Column1]="Tired", [Column3]
)
```

Or you can make it like this if you prefer:

```
Switch(
  [Column1]="Ready", [Column2],
  [Column1]="Almost", [Column2],
  [Column1]="Working", [Column3],
  [Column1]="Tired", [Column3]
)
```